# Python Difference between PySerial.write(val=raw_input()) and PySerial.write(string)?

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-uno, pyserial

In trying to perform half-duplex communication between Python (on Win10 PC) and Arduino (Uno), I'm sending some string commands from the PC to the ARD, and depending on the read string input sending back either a special statement or echoing the read info back.

To test this I wrote a very basic set of scripts for the Arduino and Python.

Arduino:

```
// Test
// <python_script.py>

// https://github.com/fortruce/fortruce.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2014-8-31-talking-to-arduino-with-python.md

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    //Serial.setTimeout(10000); // change from 1s to 10s timeout.
    pinMode(7, INPUT);
}

// ARD sends data to PY
void loop(){
    //Serial.write(0x41);
    //delay(1000);
    while(!Serial.available()){
        //Serial.write(0x01);
        //delay(300);
    }
    //Serial.read(); // read single byte being sent-over

    // <https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstring/>
    if(Serial.available()){
        String input = Serial.readStringUntil("\n"); // If there are available bytes to read, them them into a String

        // Functionality appears the same, whether using <readStringUntil("\n")> or <readString()>

        if(input=="*SETUP?"){
            /* Try-catch doesn't exist in C */
            // http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/
            if(Serial.availableForWrite()){
                Serial.println("ARD told to do Setup!");
            }
        }
        else if(input=="testAN"){
            float val[6]; // Size = 4 bytes per Float, = 4*6 = 24
            for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
                val[i] = analogRead(i);
            }
            if(Serial.availableForWrite()){
                Serial.print("<");
                Serial.print(val[0]);
                Serial.print(",");
                Serial.print(val[1]);
                Serial.print(",");
                Serial.print(val[2]);
                Serial.print(",");
                Serial.print(val[3]);
                Serial.print(",");
                Serial.print(val[4]);
                Serial.print(",");
                Serial.print(val[5]);
                Serial.println(">");
            }
        }
        else{
            if(Serial.availableForWrite()){
                Serial.print("ARD received: {");
                Serial.print(input);
                Serial.println("}.");
            }
        }
        // <https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/flush/>
        Serial.flush(); // wait for outgoing data to finish.
    }
}      
// EOL
```

Python:

```
# Test

# https://github.com/fortruce/fortruce.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2014-8-31-talking-to-arduino-with-python.md

import serial, time
import struct

ard = serial.Serial('COM4')

ard.reset_input_buffer()
ard.reset_output_buffer()

### Need a way to break this loop; once we get the info we want, move to the next PY step...
while(True):
    output = raw_input("Type what you want to send and hit 'Enter': ")

    ### Other forms of "output" I have tried:
    #output = "testAN" ### This is what I thought I could send...
    #output = "testAN\n"
    #output = "testAN\r"
    #output = "testAN\n\r"
    #output = "testAN\r\n"

    print("<" + unicode(output) + ">")
    ###print("b")
    ard.reset_output_buffer()
    ###print("c")
    print(ard.write(output))
    #ard.write(b"%s" % output)
    #time.sleep(0.5) # Give the ARD time to read...
    ###print("d")
    #ard.flushInput() # Wait for Input to be of 
    print("e")
    rec = ard.readline().strip("\n") # HUNG HERE
    #rec = ard.read_until("\n") # HUNG HERE

    ard.reset_input_buffer() # Reset input AFTER capture

    print("f")
    #print(rec)
    rec = rec.strip("\n") 
    print("g")
    #print(rec)

    if(">" in rec):
        print(rec) # To be sure...
        break;
    else:    
        print("Echo from ARD is: {%s}." % rec)
    # End if-else
# End while-loop

print("Data was received, now can do next thing!")

# EOL
```

As soon as I swap the

```
output = raw_input("Input: ") # type 'testAN' and hit 'Enter'
```

in Python with

```
output = "testAN" # Constant string
```

, this Python script hangs at the readline() statement. Why is this? I've confirmed that the Write() is sending the same number of bytes (6), regardless of origin.

```
# e.g.
print(ard.write(raw_input(": "))) # w/input testAN  
# and 
print(ard.write("testAN"))
```

both return 6.

Comment: For reference, I'm using PySerial 3.4 and Python 2.7.13!

Comment: The Arduino does `Serial.readStringUntil("\n")` - but you are never writing a newline from the Python side, the only way that statement can complete is due to a timeout.

Comment: Jason, that's a good point; for the record I did try <readString()> before moving to <readStringUntil()>. Just added that edit to the Arduino snippet, so that others finding this post can see that.

Comment: `readString` only completes on a timeout.